# Github graphql replying with 405

Tags: github, graphql, fetch

I'm trying to get my github profile detail from github using the graphql endpoint `'https://developer.github.com/v4/explorer/'` and after creating a personal token i'm getting a 405 error, this is my code please what am I doing wrong [error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIVRr.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIVRr.png)

Comment: Please post your code as a code block, not as an image.  Images are not accessible and not searchable, so you exclude a large number of people from benefiting from or answering your question.

Comment: Yes, apologies rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

The page you're attempting to load is a UI tool to help developers explore GraphQL.  In other words, it's a normal webpage, not the GraphQL endpoint.

The error message you're getting is a 405 Method Not Allowed.  That's because you're making a `POST` request to this page, but that isn't a valid method here.  Because this is a normal webpage, you probably need to use a normal `GET` request if you want to load it.

If you're looking to make a GraphQL request, you'll need to use the proper endpoints, which is https://api.github.com/graphql.  A `POST` request is correct for that endpoint.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, was able to figure it out later on

Comment: @OjoTope mark the correct answer or post your solution to help others battling with similar issue